# how to use php in javascript for displaying date in d/M/Y format

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this code which is supposed to retrieve date in d/M/Y format. But it does not display anything. I am retrieving the value from table using jQuery and AJAX. Can you tel me the code to convert date in d/M/Y format in JavaScript

```
{
  "render" : function(data,type,row) {
    var d=<?php date('d/M/Y', strtotime(row['date_of_birth']));?>
    return d;
  }
},
```

Comment: `echo` ! and also need `date_create`

Comment: did you try with `echo` ?

Comment: $row['date_of_birth'] might help as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you don't say anything about the dateformat you are trying to create the date from, Im assuming its the standard from `MySQL` (`YYYY-mm-dd H:i:s`) because you are using row as a variable.

This aside, you have a couple of issues with your code. First of, `row` is missing the variable declaration. It shoud be `$row`

Secondly, the `<?php ?>` should be wrapped inside `''`. If you don't do this, you will get a syntax error with your javascript.

Third, you need to echo the date. Thus, ending up with a code like this:

```
{
  "render" : function(data,type,row) {
    var d='<?php echo date('d/M/Y', strtotime($row['date_of_birth']));?>';
    return d;
  }
},
```